# onChange not triggering redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I have an `input` field which takes values from the values set on the state by selecting items from a `dropdown`.

```
<Field
          name="test"
          type={"text"}
          component={props =>
          <input readOnly value={instance.state.itemType} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}
          />
          }
        />
```

However, the input value changes, but the `onChange` function is not getting triggered due to which the `handleSubmit` function does not capture the value of this `input` field.

Am I doing this right? Please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching around for a bit, I found that the `props` variable isn't exactly `props`.

It contains all the events relevant for a user.

So, I manually triggered an `onChange()` event using `props.input.onChange('myDesiredValue')`;

This is what I could come up with, sort of hacky but solves my current requirement.